# trying to get multiple nested values from jagged json array using json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to print the url and filename of the files array inside each instance that is shown. Each for instance

```
http://xbins.nyc/mvscu
mvscu.zip
http://xbins.nyc/mvsc
mvsc.zip
http://xbins.nyc/mvscjp
mvscjp.zip
```

The above is how the output should be once the code below runs.  it throws errors since it's checking the whole code for the further nested arrays.

```
{
   "accountId":"Ja4Rulez",
   "finished":"true",
   "createdAt":"2016-05-20",
   "releaseDate":"1998",
   "updatedAt":"2016-05-20",
   "expires":"1468905126822",
   "requestTableUS":{
      "tableCAPCOM":{
         "tableName":"CAPCOM",
         "partial":"true",
         "files":[
            {
               "url":"http://xbins.nyc/mvscu",
               "filename":"mvscu.zip"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "requestTableMain":{
      "tableCAPCOM":{
         "tableName":"CAPCOM",
         "partial":"true",
         "files":[
            {
               "url":"http://xbins.nyc/mvsc",
               "filename":"mvsc.zip"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "requestTableJp":{
      "tableCAPCOM":{
         "tableName":"CAPCOM",
         "partial":"true",
         "files":[
            {
               "url":"http://xbins.nyc/mvscjp",
               "filename":"mvscjp.zip"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The above query is sent to the $data variable below and then json_decoded into $obj.

```
<?php

$obj = json_decode($data, TRUE);

foreach($obj as $row){
  foreach($row as $k){
    foreach($k as $j){
      foreach($j as $l){
        echo $l['url'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo $l['filename'];
        echo "<br />";
      }
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Also the number of returned "requestTable"s returned vary but here it's simply 3, but it can change from 3 to 100+. I need to make sure the loop can accommodate additional "requestTables" if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the elements of `$obj` are not arrays, so you can't use `foreach` on them. You only want to drill down into the elements whose keys begin with `requestTable`, and then you only want to loop through the `files`, not everything in that element.

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $row) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 12) == 'requestTable')) {
        foreach ($row['tableCAPCOM']['files'] as $l) {
            echo $l['url'];
            echo "<br />";
            echo $l['filename'];
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should do exactly what you want.

```
<?php
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($array as $key=>$data) {
    if (strpos($key, 'requestTable') !== false) {

        foreach($data['tableCAPCOM']['files'] as $file) {

            echo $file['url'];
            echo "<br />";
            echo $file['filename'];
            echo "<br />";

        }
    }
}
?>
```